# JNI called with jstring parameters, but one of them becomes NULL

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm calling native function from Java:

```
String pathTemp = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+Const.PATH_TEMP
String pathFiles = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+Const.PATH_FILES
engine.init(someInt, pathTemp, pathFiles);
```

And I have the native function:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void Java_com_engine_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject __unused obj, jint someInt, jstring pathTemp, jstring pathFiles) {
const char *pathTemp_ = env->GetStringUTFChars(pathTemp, JNI_FALSE); 
const char *pathFiles_ = env->GetStringUTFChars(pathFiles, JNI_FALSE); // <-- CRASH

// More init code

env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pathTemp, pathTemp_);
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(pathRecording, pathRecording_);
```

}

The problem: pathTemp is arriving good, but pathFiles==NULL in native function.
Rechecked, and confirmed - both strings are non NULL in java.

One more strange thing - The problem is on LG-G3 (android 6.0).
On Meizu PRO 5 (android 7.0) - everything works good - both strings are intact.

What is this JNI magic? Any clue?

Comment: Could you post a complete, minimal example that reproduces this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as this and while I can't guarantee this is the same, I found a better solution than re-ordering the parameters.

tldr; Ensure the code works for 32bit and 64bit platforms as pointers have different sizes. I was running 32bit native code and passed `nullptr` as a parameter and java expected a `long` which resulted in all parameters after the `nullptr` to be invalid.

`(JJLjava/lang/String;Z)V` -> `(final long pCallback, final long pUserPointer, final String id, final boolean b)`

pCallback was always set to a valid value (pointer casted to `jlong` in c++) and pUserPointer was always `nullptr`. I found this answer and tried switching the order around and it 'just worked' but I knew that fix was never going to be approved.

After looking at the JNI documentation on the Android website again (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni) I took note of the "64-bit considerations" section and took a stab at my assumption of the data size. This feature was developed with a 64bit device (Pixel 3) but issues had been reported on a 32bit device (Amazon Fire Phone) so `nullptr` would be 32bit but the java function still expected a long (64bit).

In my situation the offending parameter was always unused so I could safely remove it and everything "just worked" (including some other parameters which were broken).

An alternative would be to have a define/function/macro for JniLongNullptr which is just 0 casted to jlong.

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer, but workaround. Moved the strings (in parameters) to be before int parameter. Now it's working. I have no idea why is this.

Comment: I wouldn't even say this is a workaround.  All you've done is change what memory is getting corrupted.  Hopefully.  Instead of [Easter-egg debugging and hoping](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/E/Easter-egging.html), you'd do better actually trying to find what code is corrupting memory.